# why does canvas.captureStream() is maxing out my CPU when I have a video and image on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, redux-thunk

**The context**

I have a canvas with a the user's video piped in along with an image. The canvas is running in a loop to repaint the video and image at 30 fps. This set up take around 25% of the CPU, which I'm okay with. My recording function is called within a Redux Thunk, which get a dispatch when the recording starts and when the recording finishes.

My configuration is Windows 10, with 8GB of ram, and running in the latest version of Chrome. Everything runs client side.

**The code**

The below code is what I'm using to record the canvas.

```
export const startRecordingStream =(audioStream) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const canvas = window.document.getElementById('canvas');
    let recordStream;

    if ('captureStream' in canvas) {
        recordStream = canvas.captureStream(25);
    } else if ('mozCaptureStream' in canvas) {
        recordStream = canvas.mozCaptureStream();
    } else if (!options.disableLogs) {
        console.error('Upgrade to latest Chrome or otherwise enable this flag: chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features');
    }

    recordStream.addTrack(audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
    let recorder = null;
    const options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=h264'};
    try {
     recorder = new MediaRecorder(recordStream, options);
    } catch (e){
      console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder', + e)
    }
    recorder.start();
    recorder.chunks = [];
    recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
      event.data.size &&  event.currentTarget.chunks.push(event.data)
    }
    recorder.onpause = event => {
      console.log('paused', event)
    }
    recorder.onresume = event => {
      console.log('resume', event)
    }
    recorder.onstop = function(event) {
      dispatch({
          type: "STOP_RECORDING",
          payload: event
        });
    }
      dispatch({
            type: "START_RECORDING",
            payload: recorder
          });   
   }
  }
```

**The problem**

The moment I run this function the CPU starts to max out.

**The question**

Is is normal for my CPU to max out given that the canvas is 1080p wide, and has a video and image continously looping throught it?

Comment: Second question: you ought to just try it yourself. Your question is a bit broad and will be hard to get a definitive answer, just opinions, which is not what SO is for

Comment: What if you use the default VP8 codec instead of Chrome only h264? Now, for the CPU usage, yes, it's quite an expensive operation to encode on the fly, but it's also hard to tell if it is normal, given we don't know anything about your config. For the second part, that would *logically*, just add more burden to the CPU to deal with two streams instead of one, can't see the rationale behind it...

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks, I got the tip and removed the second question.

Comment: I found that I can reduce excessive CPU burden by reducing the frame rate to 15 FPS. Although the video is a tiny bit choppy for my purposes it will pass as acceptible.